# steering angle sensor in indian cars

Tags: sensor, steering

Does Indian cars have steering angle sensor?
Actually what I have to see if a car travels straight when made to move on straight line and determine if there is some problem with alignment.

Comment: You may want to add a little more detail to your question, such as make/model/year of car in question. This will help with giving you an accurate answer.

Comment: Indian cars with manual as well as automatic transmission like "Maruti Suzuki Swift"...also what i am trying to do is fetching data from that sensor and estimating if a car needs a wheel alignment. am i clear now ? please let me know..

Comment: Please add more information about the specific car to your original post. This is like asking if steering wheel sensors are in American cars. Some have them, some don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some cars have them, some don't. It depends on options the car has. The make, model, trim level, and target market all factor in to this.

Steering wheel angle sensors are typically used for stability control. The first clue would be if the car has some type of stability control--then it most likely has a steering angle sensor. The next step would be if this sensor data can be read through a diagnostic port (nowadays, OBD-II port). Some manufacturers allow the reading of this (typically via the CAN-BUS), some do not. [Ford's OpenXC](http://openxcplatform.com/), for example, allows reading this and other data points easily.